# Dashing job get_event?

Tags: html, ruby, dashing

In my dashboard I have a job where I would like to get a value from my widget.

```
# :first_in sets how long it takes before the job is first run. In this case, it is run immediately
SCHEDULER.every '1s', :first_in => 0 do |job|
  send_event('my_widget', { value: rand(400) })
end
```

This is the code to send data to my widget, but how could I get the data? What is the "`get_event`" that I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this issue](https://github.com/Shopify/dashing/issues/298) in dashing github repository, You can use [server sent events](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/) to get data from dashing dashboard.

Dashing provides data from the same API end point

> http://dashingdemo.herokuapp.com/events

Excerpt from returned data

> data: {"current":77,"last":82,"id":"valuation","updatedAt":1461840437}
>
> data: {"current":104578,"last":89199,"id":"karma","updatedAt":1461840437}
>
> data: {"value":62,"id":"synergy","updatedAt":1461840437}